# Selenium Not Adding Extensions Chrome Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Chrome runs fine, just when it is open, the extension is not installed.

This is my code, any help would be amazing.

````
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions


chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension(
    r'C:\Users\andre\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\92.0.4515.107\uBlock-Origin_v1.37.2.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    r"C:\Users\andre\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\92.0.4515.107\chromedriver.exe")```
````

Comment: You need to pass the options to the chrome driver: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(..., optionns= chrome_options)`

Comment: Thank you I got it to work you are amazing!!